# angular ng-hide when something is already showing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi I already have a div showing based on a ng-show condition coming from the condition being true.  How can I click on the

tag where it says download later and use ng-hide to make the div go away?

```
<div  ng-repeat="item in items">
<div class="download-now" ng-show="connected && item.purchased &&    !isDownloaded(item.guidebook_file)">

<h4>New Guide Found</h4>
<button ng-click="download(item.guidebook_file)" class="button    button-block button-positive">
Download</button>
<p>Download Later</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try ng-if instead and put your conditions in there where you can flip the flag dynamically.

Comment: thanks for responding but I dont want it done dynamically.  I want the user to be able to click the p tag and make the div where ng-show is go away :)